# Rendering different content on partial views each time user clicks

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-core-2.0, url.action

I know how to render a partial view with jquery.

Now, I am trying to render different content in the same div element each time the user click (using partial views).

I have a method in my home controller

```
public IActionResult Details(int x)
        {

            Blog A = new Blog() { Id = 1};    
            Blog B = new Blog() { Id = 2};

            if (B.Id == x)
               return PartialView("_blogPartial", B);

      return PartialView("_blogPartial", A);

        }
```

I am rendering this partial view on click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// For button 1

    $("button1").click(function () {
        $("#partial").load('@Url.Action("Details", new { x = 1})');
    });

 // For button 2
    $("#button2").click(function () {

        $("#partial").load('@Url.Action("Details",new { x=2})');
    });
});
```

And below are the two buttons .

```
<button id="button1">BlogA</button>
<button id="button2">BlogB</button>
<div id="partial">

</div>
```

**The problem:** If there are 'n' buttons I have to write click function 'n' times for each button. Is there any way that I can pass **my button id** to the **Url.Action()** method which will pass it to the Details method.

I need to do something like

```
$("button").click(function () {
        $("#partial").load('@Url.Action("Details", new { x = buttonid })');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than and `id` attribute, its more appropriate to use `data-` attributes, and then use a class name so you only need one script

```
<button data-id="1" class="blog" type="button">BlogA</button>
<button data-id="2" class="blog" type="button">BlogB</button>

var url = '@Url.Action("Details")';
var partial = $('#partial'); //cache it
$('.blog').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    partial.load(url, { x: id });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign click event for the class as I have done below.
Here I assign `btnClass` as class for the each button and make the click event t for the button's class as `$(".btnClass").click(function () {});`.

Inside this event you can get the button id using the statement as `$(this).attr('id')`.

Your html should like.

```
<button class="btnClass" id="button1">BlogA</button>
<button class="btnClass" id="button2">BlogB</button>
<div id="partial">

</div>
```

and Jquery should like as below

```
  $(".btnClass").click(function () {
       $(this).attr('id');//to get the button id
    });
```

Comment: Had to parse it, to convert into integer and then compare . But worked . Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-attribute` and store the id on each the button.

```
// render this within a loop
<button class="myButton" data-id="2">some text</button>
<button class="myButton" data-id="3">some more text</button>


  $('.myButton').click(function (e) {
       $(e.target).attr('data-id'); the button id to pass to the url
    });
```